# How to use the value from ajax function outside the success block

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am very new to Ajax and under major deadline.

I have an ajax function

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'CritAdd.php?',
    data: { currfilterfields : currfilterfields },
    async: false,
    success: function(msg) {
        var javminmaxarray = $.parseJSON(msg);
        alert(msg);
        alert(javminmaxarray);
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine and the data gets stored in global variable array "javminmaxarray". Alerts put for testing also show expected values.

However when I use this global array in my function where it needs to be accessed as below, the value shows as empty/undefined.

```
function closemodal() {
    alert(javminmaxarray[0]);
}
```

I made asynch option of ajax as false but that didn't work either. Please suggest how to use the value from ajax function outside the success block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this..

```
var javminmaxarray = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

to

```
javminmaxarray = $.parseJSON(msg);
```

Comment: This worked. I had declared javminmaxarray globally but left var declaration in success block by error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

declare you `javminmaxarray` variable outside the `$.ajax` function .

```
var javminmaxarray = {};

// .... 

$.ajax({
   //...
   success: function(msg) {
      javminmaxarray = $.parseJSON(msg);
   }
});
```

and then use your function how ever you want

```
function closemodal(){
    alert(javminmaxarray[0]);}
```

Comment: This worked. I had declared javminmaxarray globally but left var declaration in success block by error. Thank you.